# Removing paypal express checkout radio button from checkout page

Tags: paypal, magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento

I have the paypal express checkout button in my shopping cart page and checkout page. I want to remove the paypal express checkout radio button, only from the payment information step of one page checkout.

I have tried removing the below code from the xml file located in

app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/paypal.xml

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name=\"checkout.cart.top_methods\">
        <block type=\"paypal/express_shortcut\" name=\"checkout.cart.methods.paypal_express\" template=\"paypal/express/shortcut.phtml\"/>
    </reference>

    <reference name=\"checkout.cart.methods\">
        <block type=\"paypal/express_shortcut\" name=\"checkout.cart.methods.paypal_express\" template=\"paypal/express/shortcut.phtml\"/>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

But it doesn't work. any idea how to do this exactly ?

Answer (score 1):

You are editing checkout_cart_index - meaning you are removing the button from the cart.
You could do this with css and a bit of modification of template/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml:
Change

```
<dt>
```

to

```
<dt class="<?php echo $_code; ?>">
```

for example and

```
<dd>
```

to

```
<dd class="<?php echo $_code; ?>">
```

Now you yan add this to your stylesheet:

```
.sp-methods .paypal_express { display:none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you refresh the magento cache and check again.